# Using the versionCatalog plugin within a Multi Module Project - Gradle kts

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle Kotlin mutli module project and want to be able to use the versionCatalog that is built in one of the modules within the same project.

The versionCatalog is built using the `version-catalog` plugin in the sub module `issuing-commons-dependency` and looks like such:

```
plugins {
    `version-catalog`
    `maven-publish`
}

catalog {
    versionCatalog {
        version("spring-boot-version", "2.5.12")

        plugin("spring-boot-plugin", "org.springframework.boot").versionRef("spring-boot-version")

        library("spring-webflux", "org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-webflux").versionRef("spring-boot-version")
        library("spring-web", "org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-web").versionRef("spring-boot-version")
    }
}


publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            from(components["versionCatalog"])
        }
    }
}
```

So I was thinking that I could do something like this in the root level

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(":commons-dependency")
        }
    }
}
```

- causes error `Cannot resolve external dependency :commons-dependency because no repositories are defined`

Or something like this at the subproject level

```
val libs = project.rootProject
        .extensions
        .getByType(VersionCatalogsExtension::class.java)
        .named("libs")
```

- causes error `Exception is: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: Extension of type 'VersionCatalogsExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension, BasePluginExtension, DefaultArtifactPublicationSet, SourceSetContainer, ReportingExtension, JavaPluginExtension, JavaToolchainService, TestingExtension, KotlinJvmProjectExtension, KotlinTestsRegistry, JacocoPluginExtension, SonarQubeExtension, DetektExtension, IdeaModel, AllOpenExtension, PublishingExtension, ScriptingExtension]`

I am using `gradle-7.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

Can add this to the settings.gradle.kts but it will not work after a clean build.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("dependency/build/version-catalog/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use this to get the depenecency in the sub projects build.gradle.kts

```
val versionCatalog: org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultVersionCatalog = 
    (project(":issuing-commons-dependency")
        .extensions
        .getByType(CatalogPluginExtension::class.java) as 
            org.gradle.api.plugins.catalog.internal.CatalogExtensionInternal)
        .versionCatalog.get()

fun org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultVersionCatalog.buildDownload(alias: String): String {
    val dependency = this.getDependencyData(alias)
    return "${dependency.group}:${dependency.name}:${dependency.version}"
}


dependencies {
    implementation(versionCatalog.buildDownload("spring-web"))
}
```